# Html image hotspot switch image

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an image hotspot  on a map which swops the image out on hover however I would like keep the image open for longer and only have it close (and change back to the original) if the users moves their cursor outside of the new swapped image outline instead of the original hotspot, is something like this possible?

Herewith my code so far

```
<div class="mapwrap" style="text-align:center;"><img src="/dev/test/templates/jwd25template/images/map-blank.png" alt="wc" name="map" width="700" height="400" usemap="#mapMap" id="map" border="0" ></div>
<map name="mapMap">
<area shape="poly" coords="231,299,236,309,239,314,242,324,242,333,241,340,237,342,232,342,232,346,236,348,239,352,242,359,244,360,246,363,249,371,245,374,243,378,244,379,252,373,253,375,255,378,255,380,260,382,260,381,266,384,269,387,272,389,275,390,276,390,279,390,287,386,288,383,293,381,298,380,303,379,306,379,307,380,310,380,314,378,317,378,320,378,322,376,325,374,330,372,337,370,342,370,347,372,349,372,355,372,358,370,359,369,355,366,352,363,354,358,356,358,354,355,349,354,348,354,342,355,339,352,339,348,341,344,344,339,349,337,352,332,352,327,357,325,362,324,370,323,373,316,372,312,367,309,366,310,360,308,355,311,350,315,346,317,342,315,337,313,331,310,327,307,326,314,325,318,323,322,321,324,314,324,309,327,306,330,304,334,303,335,300,337,297,339,294,341,291,341,288,341,283,339,280,334,280,329,283,325,283,324,277,328,271,331,269,334,269,335,266,327,269,321,266,319,264,317,257,315,257,310,256,302,255,296,255,292,254,286,246,281,239,280,240,285,233,287,231,293,229,296,229,296" href="takke/western-cape" target="_parent" alt="WC" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('map','','/dev/test/templates/jwd25template/images/map-WC-2.png',1)"  onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore('map','','/dev/test/templates/jwd25template/images/map-blank.png',1)"></map>
```

I tried to add a onMouseOut url but I realise that wont work.

Trying to wrap my head around it, any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with CSS**

*HTML CODE:*

```
<map id="big_map_area">
  <area shape="poly" id="map_hover" coords="231,299,2..." href="takke/western-cape" target="_parent" alt="WC">
</map>
```

*CSS CODE:*

```
#map_hover {
opacity:0.0;
}
```

*JQUERY CODE:*

```
 $("#map_hover").mouseover(function () {
     this.css('opacity', '1.0');
 });
 $("#big_map_area").mouseout(function () {
     $("#map_hover").css('opacity', '0.0');
 });
```

> So you show your image when mouse enter in small poligon that is inside tha map, and image swap when you leave the big map container.

Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you, however that still doesn't solve the problem that when hovering a part of the map the new image shouldn't close until the mouse moves out of it, not out of the hotspot behind it. (usually the hotspots are behind the swapped image so when you move the cursor out of the hotspot below it, it changes - the idea is that a user can select their region by hovering, launch the swapped image, point around the swapped image (click if necessary) and then when the mouse leaves replace the swapped image with the original)

Comment: You need javascript for that. Be more specific. ;)

Comment: Basically once the swap happens I want the new image not to close when the mouse moves out of the hotspot which launched it, it should only close when you move out of the newly swapped image. Here is my example - http://marktoe.co.za/dev/agrimark/takke
See,  if I hover over the bottom left province it does launch the swop, cool, but then unless I keep the mouse very still it will swap back when my cursor moves out of the provinces outline hotspot below the swopped image (most users will track their mouse over the popped up image out of habit causing the image to close prematurely)

Comment: i got it. You need some javascript here.

Comment: Thank you, ideed I do understand, however JS isnt my strongpoint so I was merely wondering which direction I should be looking ie functions etc I am happy to research it but just not sure what to actually research

Comment: Ok this is what I end up with but still no luck - http://pastebin.com/W1tDkpBR
Currently I am using the same swop image for each area (so its deceptive) and but when I move out of the polygon the image still disappears. You can also see when moving the cursor that there are links of the other hotspots still there. Id like to hide these until the cursor has moved out of the entire map frame

Comment: Any ideas on the JS I could use to keep the swopped image open until I move out of the maps container? I tried playing around with it but have no clue where to look, the part getting me is, 
1. how do I use JS to prevent the replace image (after the swop) from closing?
2. and how can I then make it only close once the mouse leaves the swopped image (large map container)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - need to get this working desperately :)